# How to read and map the values from an xml to java in larger files

Tags: xml

I have an xml where i need to extract the values from them and update it in database.

The xml is very large may be 1gb or more.

Which is the most efficient way to parse it and extract it.

Will Xpath be fast?

Comment: I suggest that you look this article. http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/09/07/schema-less-java-xml-data-binding-with-vtd-xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some sort of streaming approach with large files like that, what is easiest depends on the structure of the XML. If it's made up of lots of fragments that can be handled independently, for example

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <col name="col1">value1</col>
    <col name="col2">value2</col>
  </row>
  <!-- and another million row elements -->
</rows>
```

then there are what I call "semi-streaming" ways to stream through the file parsing one `row`, processing it, then throwing it away and parsing the next etc. using a tool like [XOM](http://xom.nu) (look up "custom node factories") or JAXB (define an object model that represents one `row`, then create an XMLStreamReader on your document and unmarshal one row at a time).

Answer (score 0):

XPath will likely be very slow on such a large document. You'll likely be better off using a streaming parser (SAX/StAX) and extracting the information you need on the go.